# Why were Series 6 and 7 split into two parts?

Tags: doctor-who, behind-the-scenes, production

Nearly every series of new (post-2005) *Doctor Who*, excluding specials, has comprised a sequence of weekly episodes:

- Series 1: weekly from 26 March 2005 to 18 June 2005
- Series 2: weekly from 15 April 2006 to 8 July 2006
- Series 3: weekly from 31 March 2007 to 30 June 2007, with one two-week gap
- Series 4: weekly from 5 April 2008 to 5 July 2008, with one two-week gap
- Series 5: weekly from 3 April 2010 to 26 June 2010
- Series 8: weekly from 23 August 2014 to 8 November 2014
- Series 9: weekly from 19 September 2015 to 5 December 2015

With the exceptions of Series 6 and 7, which were each split into two halves with a period of months in between:

- Series 6: weekly from 23 April 2011 to 4 June 2011, then weekly from 27 August 2011 to 1 October 2011
- Series 7: weekly from 1 September 2012 to 29 September 2012, then weekly from 30 March 2013 to 18 May 2013

Plot-wise, each of these splits sort of makes sense: the first half of Series 6 ends with

> the revelation that River Song is Melody Pond, Amy and Rory's daughter,

while the first half of Series 7 ends with

> Amy and Rory being lost to the Doctor forever,

with a Christmas special in the middle of Series 7 to introduce the new character of Clara.

But **what was the out-of-universe reason for these splits?** Why did Moffat or whoever make the decision to split the transmission of each of Series 6 and 7 into two separate chunks?

Comment: *"This [split] reportedly came about as a result of writer Steven Moffat's desire to write an entire new story arc for the Doctor, which will conclude with a potentially huge cliffhanging plot development at the end of the spring. We can, therefore, expect seven episodes in the first half of 2011, and a further six towards the end of the year"* - http://www.denofgeek.com/tv/doctor-who/20589/doctor-who-series-6-mid-season-hiatus-reaction#ixzz4DpGhVdLO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Series 6

The BBC released a press-release to explain the decision, citing that by making fans wait, it would increase their overall enjoyment.

> *The BBC and Steven Moffat have announced today that the transmission
> of the next series of Doctor Who, in 2011, will be split into two
> blocks, transmitting in spring and autumn.*
>
> ***The split transmission is the result of a request from Steven Moffat
> to write a new Doctor Who story arc which involves a big plot twist in
> the middle of the series. By splitting the series Moffat plans to give
> viewers one of the most exciting Doctor Who cliffhangers and plot
> twists ever, leaving them waiting, on the edge of their seats, until
> the autumn to find out what happens.***
>
> *Steven Moffat said: “The split series is hugely exciting because
> viewers will be treated to two premieres, two finales and more event
> episodes. For the kids it will never be more than a few months to the
> next Doctor Who! Easter, Autumn, Christmas!!”*
>
> <sub><sup>[DOCTOR WHO NEWS: SERIES 6 SPLIT CONFIRMED](http://www.doctorwhotv.co.uk/series-6-split-confirmed-8821.htm)</sup></sub>

### Series 7

In this letter to angry fans, Patrick McManus from the BBC complaints dept again justified the split in Season 7 on "creative grounds"

> *Additionally, please note that the decision to schedule series 7 in
> two parts was a creative one and we’re sorry you are unhappy about
> this.*
>
> <sub><sup>[BBC forced to react to fan fury over split Who S7 + 50th special](http://www.blastr.com/2013-2-11/bbc-forced-react-fan-fury-over-split-who-s7-50th-specials)</sup></sub>

According to [showrunner Steven Moffat](http://www.blastr.com/2012/05/steven_moffat_shares_the.php), the plan for Season 7 was to leave as short a gap as possible between the end of the series and the (very expensive) [50th year celebration episode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Day_of_the_Doctor).

> *"I don't know, on this occasion, that the thinking particularly came
> from me, actually. I've always been open to anything that shakes [the
> series] up. **I think that decision actually came from the BBC.***
>
> *"But I've been well up for anything that we can do to shake up the
> transmission pattern, the way we deliver it to the audience and how
> long we make the audience wait, simply because that makes Doctor Who
> an event piece.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Steven Moffat shares the reason he's messing with Who's schedule](http://www.blastr.com/2012/05/steven_moffat_shares_the.php)</sup></sub>

He also argued that moving the transmission dates around *randomly* makes audiences feel better about Dr Who in general.

> *"So keeping Doctor Who as an event, and never making people feel, 'Oh,
> it's lovely, reliable old Doctor Who — it'll be on about this time, at
> that time of year'. Once you start to do that, just slowly, it becomes
> like any much-loved ornament in your house — ultimately invisible. And
> I don't want that to ever be the case."*
>
> <sub><sup>[Steven Moffat shares the reason he's messing with Who's schedule](http://www.blastr.com/2012/05/steven_moffat_shares_the.php)</sup></sub>

---

### Real reasons

The cynic in me suspects that the decision was *actually* taken in order to double the number of season-openings and season-finales (potentially increasing the viewing figures which had taken a slide) and hence **sell more overseas advertising and box-sets.** You can see the mid-season bumps [here](http://www.themindrobber.co.uk/ratings.html).

It may also be pertinent to point out that the next season wasn't slated for production until February the following year, with transmission of Season 7 nearly ***18 months*** after the point that the previous season should normally have ended. **A gap that big would have angered fans greatly.**

Comment: Muchas gracias. Good find. I bet the internet absolutely *exploded* in mid-2011 with speculation about the revelation at the end of Series 6a.

Comment: "*A gap that big would have angered fans greatly*" - you mean like this effing big gap we're in the middle of now? :-)

Comment: @Randal'Thor - See. Now imagine how you'd feel if they announced that the next episode wasn't until *August* 2017.

Comment: _"leaving them waiting, on the edge of their seats, until the autumn"_ Surely this breaks some human rights laws